# javascript: object property is array, but append isn't working

Tags: javascript

```
var objs = {
   'prop': []
}
objs['prop'].append('q');
```

Error: `TypeError: objs.prop.append is not a function`

Why this code is not working ? 
Why `console.log(typeof(objs['prop']));` is `object` not `array` ?

Comment: typeof is a red herring. (typeof new Array()) = "object" in Javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**Array.push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var objs = {
   'prop': []
}
objs['prop'].append('q');
```

should be:

```
var objs = {
   'prop': []
}
objs['prop'].push('q');
```

Answer (score 3):

Because there are no associative arrays in JavaScript, an associative array is actually an Object. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Don't know how this is related to the question.

Comment: @JaredPar It is an answer to the second question, about why `typeof` an array returns `"object"`